# Multi tables filter calculation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two tables:

1 - dates with user id:

> dateStart, dateEnd,userId

2 - users with allowedAmount:

> userid,allowedAmount

I am trying to perform filter as following - return only the:

> (dateEnd-dateStart)/allowedAmount

I know how i can filter as following

```
qs = qs.filter(dateStart__range=[dateStart, dateEnd])
qs = qs.filter(dateEnd__range=[dateStart, dateEnd])
```

but i am struggling on filtering by the result of the above requirement using DJANGO's queryset filter
any suggestions?